# OS X Lion: How to disable RPC?

Tags: macos, administrator

[Remote procedure calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) are considered to be a security risk. Is there a way for me to disable RPCs on OS X to make my Mac more secure?

Comment: What is RPC? Some clarification might be helpful so we know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Here are my recommended settings for locking down your Mac. I'm assuming you're running OS X Lion. If that's not the case, let me know and I'll try to adjust my answer for other versions of OS X.

**Turn your Firewall on:** System Preferences -> Security & Privacy Tab Settings -> Firewall tab. Make sure it's on and that you click the lock in the lower left corner to prevent changes without an administrator's password.

[image: Firewall On]

**Turn off all sharing services:** System Preferences -> Sharing Settings -> Make sure all the stuff in that window is unchecked. Make sure the lock in the lower left corner is locked to prevent changes without an administrator's password.

[image: All sharing services off]

**Turn off Bonjour (mDNSResponder):** For OS Lion you don't need to completely disable mDNSResponder (which is good because if you disable it completely you lose DNS in Snow Leopard and newer OS X). Instead you can follow [these steps to disable just Bonjour features in mDNSResponder](http://www.remotemacserver.com/?p=20) (**Note:** do this carefully as a malfunctioning mDNSResponder service can prevent a Mac from booting. Make sure you have a TimeMachine backup before making changes and that booting to your recovery partition works.):

1. Make a back up copy of the mDNSResponder.plist file as a precaution.
2. Open the `mDNSResponder.plist` file in Terminal using your preferred text editor. Here is a sample command:

   ```
   sudo nano “/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist”
   ```
3. Add `<string>-NoMulticastAdvertisements</string>` to the array in the `ProgramArguments` section. In other words:

   ```
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
   <string>/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder</string>
   <string>-launchd</string>
   </array>
   ```

   becomes…

   ```
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
   <string>/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder</string>
   <string>-launchd</string>
   <string>-NoMulticastAdvertisements</string>
   </array>
   ```
4. Save the file.
5. Restart your Mac.

You may also want to look at locking down BlueTooth on the system (System Preferences -> BlueTooth Settings). Specifically you may want to uncheck 'Discoverable' so your BlueTooth chipset doesn't advertise itself to other devices nearby. If you're not using any BlueTooth devices consider turning it off altogether.

Comment: It's worthwhile noting that disabling Bonjour can disable functionality such as iTunes Home Sharing and AirPlay.

Comment: No doubt. All those things use Bonjour to discover each other an then do their work through their RPC interfaces.

Comment: I encountered some trouble to set this up because I always edited the file using TextMate. DNS resolving would not work anymore. However, once I edited the file with nano it worked...?!

Comment: @gentmatt that's weird. TM should be friendly for this kind of edit.